# Snowball search_analyzer not working with multi_match query

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I am trying to do a query against an index using the snowball analyzer. It appears to not be working correctly. If I type in "starbucks" it will return 0 results however if I type in "starbuck" it returns all data with "Starbucks" in the name.

I know that when doing a normal search you must explicitly specify the field in order for a search_analyzer to be utilized.

Is it strange that _mapping says I am using the snowball index_analyzer but doesn't mention the snowball search_analyzer?

Mapping Snippet:

```
name: {
            type: "string",
            search_analyzer : "snowball", 
            index_analyzer : "snowball",
            boost : 1
      },
tags: {
            type: "string",
            search_analyzer : "snowball", 
            index_analyzer : "snowball",
            boost : 4
      }
```

Snippet from /businesses/business/_mapping

```
name: {type: "string",analyzer: "snowball"},
tags: {type: "string",boost: 4,analyzer: "snowball"}
```

Java Code to do my search:

```
val response = client.prepareSearch("businesses")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(termQuery("name", term))
        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Comment: analyzer means search_analyzer and index_analyzer are the same. That sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term specified in `termQuery` is not analyzed and used as is. Since the word `Starbucks` i s indexed as term `starbuck` you are able to get some results back. When you are searching for the term `Starbucks` there is no such term in the index and you are not getting any results. I would recommend using `text` query instead, which will perform analysis of your term.

```
val response = client.prepareSearch("businesses")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(text("name", term))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also resolved it by doing a multi_match query. That seems to have properly enforced the search analyzer.

```
val customQuery = customScoreQuery(
        filteredQuery(
            multiMatchQuery("Gamestop".toLowerCase())
                .field("tags")
                .field("name"), 
            geoDistanceFilter("location")
            .point(40.76405282025, -73.972994269042)
            .distance(10, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS)
        )
     )
     .script("customscript")
     .lang("native")
     .param("lat",40.76405282025)
     .param("lon",-73.972994269042)

    val response = client.prepareSearch("businesses")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
        .setQuery(customQuery)
        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

This is also a good example of combining a custom score query with a filtered multi match query using the geodistance filter.